# MacVim not loading ftplugins

Tags: python, vim, macvim, restructuredtext, ftplugin

I've been wrestling with macvim for the past few days using an ftplugin. I can't seem to solve my issue, despite numerous attempts.

MacVim is installed on my computer (via Homebrew) and is using the proper python.

```
    bash-3.2# mvim --version
    VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Sep 24 2013 14:52:41)
    MacOS X (unix) version
    Included patches: 1-754
    Compiled by Homebrew
    Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
    [irrelevant stuff omitted]
    +persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile +python/dyn -python3 +quickfix
```

I have a .vimrc that simply says `filetype plugin on`. There is nothing else in my `.vimrc`; I tried using a clean file in case that was my issue.

If relevant, I am trying to use the `vim-rst-tables` plugin (https://github.com/nvie/vim-rst-tables).

I pip installed vim_bridge and can do `:python import vim_bridge` within vim without any issues.

Anyways, if I keep the filename, `rst-tables.vim` in `~/.vim/ftplugin/` - the return of `:scriptnames` does not show anything related to `~/.vim/ftplugin/*`. If I change the plugin name from `rst-tables.vim` to `rst.vim`, I see `36: ~/.vim/ftplugin/rst.vim`. This seems like it would be a good thing, but still none of the functionality works - i.e. `,,c` and `,,f`.

If anyone has any insight or more information I could provide that would help in debugging, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Plugin problem? Plugin [issue tracker](https://github.com/nvie/vim-rst-tables/issues).

Comment: Is there any reason why you installed MacVim via homebrew not via the dmg from the MacVim site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name `rst-tables.vim` won't work, as per the rules (cp. `:help ftplugins`), it must be either `rst_tables.vim` or `rst/tables.vim`. Renaming should get it sourced. Any remaining issues with the plugin should be addressed to the plugin's author; he's best suited to help. You can check whether expected mappings have been defined with e.g. `:verbose map ,,c`.

Comment: Thanks, it still doesn't work, but I guess I will bring it up to the plugin creator.